# node-webkit and WebGL on Linux

Tags: linux, webgl, node-webkit

Can someone confirm that WebGL works with node-webkit on Linux distros?

I can make WebGL run on Google Chrome after enabling the flag `Override software rendering list` on `chrome://flags/`, but I'm getting errors regarding Three.js when trying to execute the same application on node-webkit.

Comment: check [this out](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Yep, I've already done that and works fine on `Google Chrome`. I'm wondering how can I do the same, on native application running on `node-webkit`.

Comment: It should work on linux for those who do not have to enable the flag normally. But it sounds like your specific computer requires it. So you'll need to find a way to enable those flags in node-webkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It just depends if the system has a video driver installed that supports:

- `hardware acceleration` and
- `OpenGL ES2.0`

(the requirements for `WebGL`)

`Node-WebKit` or not, `WebGL` is gonna run smoothly, if the above requirements are met.

Comment: It should be "OpenGL ES2.0", that is the requirement for WebGL, not OpenGL 2.0.